# How to display different page content to Anonymous user and to Authenticated User in drupal 7.x?

Tags: 7

Am don't have much knowledge on drupal. Just starting my first drupal site. I created a "content" under a menu named "information". The menu "information" is given permission for both "anonymous user" and for "authenticated user" as well. As i click the menu "information" (as in anonymous user), the content i set was ***"please login as authenticated user, if you unable to login, please contact the administrator".***

Then, i login as the "Authenticated user" and i click the menu "information", am getting the same content message as ***"please login as authenticated user, if you unable to login, please contact the administrator."***Please, i don't need this content message, under "information" menu if i login as the "authenticated user".

I needs to "DISPLAY DIFFERENT PAGE CONTENT TO ANONYMOUS AND TO AUTHENTICATED USER"?
I don't know how to proceed this ? Can anybody please help me out the step by step procedure to do this task ?  Please help me out . Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 5):

The "content" and "information" part of your question doesn't make sense to me. I'm posting a general guide to displaying different content on a per *role* basis, and you can update your question/comment if you need any part clarified.

I would use Panels. You can use it on either a custom page such as "example.com/information" or on a per conent basis to display different content or parts of the content, on a per *role* basis. Example below if for "content"/"nodes".

1. Install the [Chaos tool suite (ctools)](http://drupal.org/project/ctools) module, and [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels).
2. Enable the Page Manager and Panels modules.
3. Enable the node template.
4. Create a variant of type "Panel", call it "Authenticated user view".
5. Pick a suitable layout.
6. Go to the "Selection rules" settings and add a "User:role" setting to limit viewing to a certain role, such as authenticated user.
7. Go to the content tab, and add your "Node: Content" to a suitable region so that your content shows up.
8. Repeat steps 4-6 but call the variant "Anonymous user view". Make sure it's *below* the first variant in the list.
9. Add whatever you want your anonymous users to see to the second variant.
10. Save

That should be all. Using Panels requires a bit of understanding of the tools it provides, and I probably introduced a great deal of new Drupal terms to you in this answer. I recommend you start by viewing these videos [here](http://dev.nodeone.se/en/learn-page-manager).

Answer (score 0):

This video tutorial will show you how to
display different content to different users

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cE14tLom8W8